# Creating prototypes using keynote for ipad

Tags: interaction-design, wireframe, ipad, prototype

I have hi-fi wireframes for each screen, which are flattened images in JPEG format. These wireframes can be connected by hotspots in Fireworks or any other tool that creates clickable prototypes.

How do you do the same using Keynote for iPad, as I want to show my clickable prototype as a presentation?

Keynote lets you create only hotspots for objects that are created inside the keynote and not on flat JPEGs.

Comment: Can't you create zero-opacity shapes in Keynote and place them on top of the relevant places in the JPEG?

Comment: Don't use a slideshow application to create prototypes. It's not its intended use.

Comment: @dnbrv I'd disagree. While it might not be the best tool for the job, it is actually a great tool for these type of low-fi jobs -- especially if you don't have the cash for or don't want to spend the money on a more specialized solution.

Comment: @GotDibbs: The OP is talking about "hi-fi" specifically. And money is never an issue: you can make a working clickable prototype in HTML with static pre-scripted data in any plain text editor. Any UXD who works with software is capable of learning the basic HTML to create low-fi prototypes.

Comment: I read it as a hi-fi wireframe being made into a lo-fi prototype -- either way, I still stand by my comment for lo-fi situations where one hasn't yet made the time to pick up the HTML skills necessary to really create a representative prototype. In any case it sounds like Vitaly may have the answer to the actual question here.

Answer (score 1):

The OPs question is about how to do it in Keynote, not whether or not it's the best solution. Vitaly Mijiritsky's comment is probably the most correct and easiest way to do this. You can just use shapes set to zero opacity and enable them as hyperlinks to other slides in the slideshow. this will allow you to navigate either in normal prenentation mode (1-2-3-4) or via your hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your Keynote design and run it on an iPad to test the design, have a look at http://keynotopia.com/apps/.

You export your keynote screen als clickable PDF, en load it inside the Keynotopia iPad (or iPhone) app.